# Rewrite for third party module's model not working

Tags: magento-1.7, module, model

By using the third party module, There is a option in admin configuration side to select the number of columns for the catalog page. I want to add an additional column option in the admin configuration side.

In third party module Model/Columncount.php

```
    <?php class Third_Party_Model_Columncount
    {
        public function toOptionArray()
        {
            return array(
  array('value'=>'3', 'label'=>Mage::helper('ThemeConfig')->__('3 Column Grid')),
  array('value'=>'4', 'label'=>Mage::helper('ThemeConfig')->__('4 Column Grid')),
  array('value'=>'5', 'label'=>Mage::helper('ThemeConfig')->__('5 Column Grid'))
                );
    }
    ?>
```

I need to add one more option with it,

For that I made an module to rewrite model as below

My_Module.xml

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <My_Module>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <depends><Third_Party/></depends>
    </My_Module>
  </modules>
</config>
```

in the My/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
      <My_Module>
       <version>0.1.0</version>
      </My_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
        <module>
        <class>My_Module_Model</class>
        </module>
            <party>
                <rewrite>
                    <columncount>My_Module_Model_Columncount</columncount>
                </rewrite>
            </party>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

and in My/Module/Model/Columncount.php

```
<?php class My_Module_Model_Columncount extends Third_Party_Model_Columncount
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return array(
        array('value'=>'3', 'label'=>Mage::helper('ThemeConfig')->__('3 Column Grid')),
        array('value'=>'4', 'label'=>Mage::helper('ThemeConfig')->__('4 Column Grid')),
        array('value'=>'5', 'label'=>Mage::helper('ThemeConfig')->__('5 Column Grid')),
        array('value'=>'6', 'label'=>Mage::helper('ThemeConfig')->__('6 Column Grid'));
    }

}?>
```

But it is not getting rewritten, why? Can anyone help here.

Comment: Would you please paste the code of Third/Party/etc/config.xml?

Answer (score 1):

The rewrite is fine and should work but you do have error in config.xml file

```
<module>
```

is repeated twice, second note should be closed

```
</module>
```

You can try test it using

```
get_class(Mage::getModel('party/columncount'))
```

The problem might also be related to attribute / column renderer. You need to check if the model / block uses magento class prefix ***party/columncount*** to handle renderer or if the class name is put as it is **Third_Party_Model_Columncount**

Comment: Thanks! I have corrected the mistake. Even though it is not working. If I add additional option in Third_Party_Model_Columncount, it adds the new option. So this is the file which is giving the options for configuration.